# "Dockerized" Node.js Application Not Responding to Host

Tags: node.js, docker, portforwarding

I am trying to "Dockerize" a rather large, complicated Node.js application, which is roughly structured like so:

Nebula [root directory of the project; runs the Node.js application]

|__CosmosD3 [directory that contains all HTML and JS files]

|__Nebula-Pipeline [directory that contains most Python files that do all the heavy computations]

Our standard installation process for this project is rather complicated due to all the interconnected pieces that all must work together flawlessly to enable our front end JS files to communicate with our back end Python scripts. For Linux/Unix systems, this is the rough process (with commands run from within the Nebula directory):

1. Install Java. (Just about any version should do; we have a single Java file that needs to be run for a particular interaction in the front end)
2. Install Python 2.7 and pip
3. Run `pip install --upgrade pip` to ensure the latest pip is being used
4. Install Node.js, npm, and zmq using `sudo apt-get install libzmq-dev npm nodejs-legacy`
5. Run `npm install` to install our Node.js package dependencies
6. Run `pip install -e ./Nebula-Pipeline` to install all Python dependencies
7. Pray that everything has gone smoothly and run the application with `npm start`. The default port is `8081`, so the application should be accessible through `localhost:8081`.

A very similar project to this one has already been "Dockerized." By tweaking the Dockerfile for the other project to more closely correspond to the steps above, this is the Dockerfile I've created:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN mkdir /www
WORKDIR /www
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y libzmq-dev npm nodejs-legacy python python-pip
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && \
    apt-get install -y ant && \
    apt-get clean;

# Fix certificate issues, found as of 
# https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/983302
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install ca-certificates-java && \
    apt-get clean && \
    update-ca-certificates -f;

# Setup JAVA_HOME, this is useful for docker commandline
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME

##COPY ./lib/ /opt/lib

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./Nebula /www
RUN ls -a /www
RUN npm install

RUN pip install -e /www/Nebula-Pipeline

EXPOSE 8081

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

When I run this Dockerfile with `docker build -t nebulaserver`, it appears that the image is created successfully. When I run the image with `docker run -p 8081:8081 nebulaserver`, I get the following printout that seems to indicate that everything is actually working properly. (Note that the "PORT: 8081" printout is a confirmation of the port that the Node.js app is using.)

```
Michelles-MacBook-Pro-8$ docker run -p 8081:8081 nebulaserver

> Nebula@0.0.1 start /www
> node app.js

PORT:
8081
```

However, when I subsequently try to connect to `localhost:8081`, I don't get any kind of response. Additionally, I expect to see additional printouts from my Node.js server when it receives a request for one of the HTML pages. I don't see any of these printouts either. It's as if the port forwarding is not working properly. Based on everything I've read, I should be doing things correctly, but I've never used Docker before, so perhaps I'm missing something?

Anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Here's my app.js file, in case that helps figure out what's going on...

```
/*Import packages required in package.json   */
/*Add these packages from the ../node_modules path*/
var express = require('express');//A lightweight nodejs web framework
var path = require('path');//Ability to join filepaths to filenames.
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');//Set prefered icon in browser URL bar. Unused?
var logger = require('morgan');//HTTP request logger. Unused?
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');//Stores cookies in req.cookies
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');//Middleware parser for incoming request bodies, 

/* REST API routes */
var routes = require('./routes/index');//Points to /routes/index.js.  Currently, index.js points to CosmosD3/CosmosD3.html

/* Connect to the databases */
//var mongo = require('mongodb');
//var monk = require('monk');
//var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest');
//var datasets = monk('localhost:27017/datasets');

/* The HTTP request handler */

var app = express();//Creates app from express class. (Baseline famework for an app. No web functionality).
var debug = require('debug')('Nebula:server');//Require the debug module. Pass it scoping 'Nebula:server'
var http = require('http').Server(app);//Create an http server on top of app.

/* The Socket.io WebSocket module */
var io = require('socket.io')(http);//Create an io/websocket on top of http object.

/* Our custom Nebula module handles the WebSocket synchronization */
var nebula = require('./nebula')(io);//Creates nebula layer on top of io.

/* Set the port we want to run on */
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
//app.set('port', port);
var host = '0.0.0.0';
app.listen(port, host);
console.log(`Running on http://${host}:${port}`);

/* view engine setup, currently not used */
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

/* Expose everything in public/ through our web server */
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use("/cosmos", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'CosmosD3')));

// Make our db accessible to our router
//app.use(function(req, res, next){
//    req.db = db;
//    req.datasets = datasets;
//    next();
//});

/* Initiate the REST API */
app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = (typeof port === 'string' ? 'Pipe ' + port : 'Port ' + port);

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = http.address();
  var bind = (typeof addr === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + addr : 'port ' + addr.port);
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
http.listen(port);
http.on('error', onError);
http.on('listening', onListening);
```

Comment: I don't have my computer to do test but I think I had kind of the same issue.
If so the issue is with the `CMD ["npm", "start"]` if I remember corectly it will start your instance but then shut it down, it doesn't keep it alive.
A solution was to use a supervisor or to use the Entrypoint in your DockerFile, I'll try to dig and come back.
Hope at least this can give you new ideas to test..

Comment: Try to read that 
https://blog.trifork.com/2014/03/11/using-supervisor-with-docker-to-manage-processes-supporting-image-inheritance/

I think it may be your way out.
I would cmd a supervisor in your dockerFile, with a "nodeamon = true" and with your command to run your npm

Comment: This sounds like a common symptom where the process inside the container is set to listen only on 127.0.0.1, which is a common default for development-type servers.  It needs to listen on 0.0.0.0 (“all inbound interfaces”) to be reachable from outside the container.

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't think my container is listening on port 127.0.0.1 (localhost)... Everything I've read seems to indicate that everything run in a container runs on 0.0.0.0 and that the port forwarding that I specify when I run it (`-p 8081:8081`) should be sufficient to get my host and container communicating properly... Do you know how I can check what URL my application is running on within the container just to be sure? (I'm not quite sure how I would do this since I don't have direct access to the container...)

Comment: @Niradnik I'm trying to get by without a supervisor... It doesn't seem like I really need one since I just want 1 instance of my single container running. (Plus, I'm trying to keep things as simple as possible...) Based on some examples that I've looked at, it doesn't seem like I really need a supervisor to get my container talking with my host. Or do I have a misunderstanding of how I should be setting up my application with Docker?

Comment: No you don't need a supervisor it was just an other solution to the no deamon but seems like it didn't solve your issue so..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out!! After a ton of digging around, I discovered that the default IP for Docker applications is http://192.168.99.100 as opposed to http://localhost. I got the answer from here:

https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-running-host-but-not-accessible/44082/13

Comment: Also, for anyone else who's trying to muddle through similar issues, based on what else I've seen/read since finding this answer, it sounds like the reason why I can't connect through localhost might be because I'm using the older Docker Toolbox (because my OS is too old to support the newer versions of Docker). A way to see what IP address to connect to is `docker-machine ip default`, where `default` is the name of the daemon you're connecting through to your containers. (You get `default` "out of the box" with Docker, but it sounds like you can define other daemons as well if you wish.)

Answer (score 4):

I have had this problem before and (as mentioned by @davidmaze in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55008122/dockerized-node-js-application-not-responding-to-host#comment96772225_55008122)) I had to change the host that my app was listening on. In my case, it was that I was using the [Express framework](https://expressjs.com/), which (despite the docs implying otherwise) was listening only for localhost (`127.0.0.1`), and I needed it to listen to `0.0.0.0`. See lines 58-[66](https://github.com/nodejs/nodejs.org/blame/master/locale/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp.md#L66) (which make up the 2nd code block in the [Create the Node.js app](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/#create-the-node-js-app) section of the [Dockerizing a Node.js web app](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp) example) for where they explicitly tell express to listen for `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: I tried that and got `Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:8081`, which doesn't make sense to me since I'm only using this one application. I get the same error when trying to run my application on port 80 instead.

Comment: When running your container "normally" when you can't access it from outside did you try to call it from the inside. With the docker exec command? Try and if you can reach it from the inside on the 127.0.0.1 then the issue is probably what it is said here.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "call it from the inside"... My guess is no? I shouldn't really be doing anything with that port other than listening to incoming HTTP requests to view the webpage. That's how the application works outside of Docker, at least

Comment: Doing a `docker exec - it <my_container> bash` then run your call or directly `docker exec - it <my_container> <my_command>` where I think the command will be something like a curl if you have one installed or a wget of 127.0.0.1:8081/xxxxxx

Comment: You build a container from Ubuntu images so basically your container is a "computer" on Ubuntu OS you can just go in and check if that works as you would do on a local install

Comment: sorry I didn't saw a space was added it is `-it` and not `- it`

Comment: So , I did some poking around using a much simpler app that I built exactly as specified from https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/. I'm having similar issues there where I cannot access the app from my host machine, even though I can go into the container and do `curl -i localhost:8080` or `curl -i 0.0.0.0:8080` and see the printout that I'm supposed to see. My container is still running properly and everything, according to what I see from `docker ps` from my host machine. Is there something I'm missing to get the port forwarding working properly?

Comment: Maybe it's also worth mentioning that I'm running an older version of Docker since my computer is running Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10.5), which is too old for the latest version of Docker. (My dev environment is fragile, so I've been hesitant to let my OS upgrade for fear that it will break things horribly). Also, the port forwarding issue that I'm having even with the simple test doesn't explain why my more complicated app is throwing the `EADDRINUSE` error... I'll keep poking around with that to see if I can at least resolve that issue

Comment: Alright, so, after a bit more poking around, I don't know why my app is throwing the `EADDRINUSE` error... I edited the original post to contain my app.js file for more info/context... My guess is that maybe using `app.listen(0.0.0.0, 8080)` isn't sufficient to set my app to listen on that address/port. Do I have to make some other change to get rid of this error?

Comment: Ok, I think I figured out the `EADDRINUSE` issue... I needed to have http listen on the specified host and port, not app. Still not able to access the app on my host machine though

Answer (score 0):

On a MAC, I had to put in the port in two spots:

1. in the Dockerfile I needed to put in:
   EXPOSE 5000 5010 5011
   before the CMD line (second to last line) and it exposes 3 ports
2. In docker-compose.yml  (I have two dockers)  I need to put in at the app part:
   ports:

- "5000:5000"
- "5010:5010"
- "5011:5011"